# Can dot product of vectors be done "by parts" - that is calculate two numbers based solely on one vector and later combine them?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've had to compute volumes of several objects and my first instinct was to sum the first vector (of dimensions) and multiply by the second.
That obviously won't work, so I started thinking whether using the geometric mean would help in any way, but I didn't see any obvious way to use it. So then I started to consider whether it is even possible to calculate it "by parts".

So for instance for two vectors A and B I'm wondering whether there exist two functions f and g such that both depend on a single vector and that there exists a function h which takes both results and returns the dot product of the vectors A and B.

Obviously it's not very hard to have f and g return the vectors themselves and then have h simply compute the dot product in the usual way.

Therefore I think that the real question is whether it is possible to have f and g return a vector of smaller dimensions than the input (ideally of dimension 1) and still be able to compute the dot product with h.

If you have any directions I can follow on the matter that would also be great.

Comment: Well, since, say, a bijection exists between $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R$ then the answer is "yes" in an extremely unhelpful sense.  Hard to imagine a useable way to do it...if, say, you want $\vec v \cdot \vec w=f(\vec v)\times f(\vec w)$ then, no:  $(1,0)\cdot (0,1)=0$ implies that at least one of $f(0,1)$ or $f(1,0)$ is $0$ but each of these has length $1$.

Comment: @lulu Good enough for me :) The intention behind this is to try and classify what sort of functions can do this.
Obviously there is a function as you say (forgot to consider the bijection :) ) so now I can move on to considering how much "better" I can make the function (to see whether it could be a simple one even if not linear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $n$, the vector space $\Bbb R^n$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$ itself. Hence you *could* encode any vector $\in\Bbb R^n$ a a single number $\in \Bbb R$ and then evaluate a suitable function $h$ on these two real numbers instead of the original vectors, essentially by undoing the encoding and performing the original calculation.

However, this is probably not what you want. 
A nice such map should probably be *continuous*.
But any *continuous* map $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ is not injective (just apply the Intermediate Value Theorem to two distinct arcs between two points).
And for any $f\colon\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ that is *not* injective, the intended decomposition will fail: Assume $f(\mathbf x)=f(\mathbf y)$ with $\mathbf x\ne\mathbf y$. Then with $\mathbf d=\mathbf y-\mathbf x$
$$\mathbf y\cdot\mathbf d=\mathbf x\cdot \mathbf d+ \underbrace{\mathbf d\cdot \mathbf d}_{>0}\ne \mathbf x\cdot \mathbf d$$
but
$$h(f(\mathbf x),g(\mathbf d))=h(f(\mathbf y),g(\mathbf d)).$$

Comment: Thanks :) I have a followup:
1) How bad will the function have to be? Can it be continuous by parts and work? Specifically how "good" can injective functions be from R2 to R (I'm basically more interested in a function that can be computed easily than a function that must be continuous)
2) What is the "problem" in the dot product that causes this? Specifically when can you decompose a function p(x,y) to a h(f(x),g(y)) when the sum of dimensions of f and g is smaller than the sum of dimensions of x and y and both continuous?

[[if I you'd rather I ask in another question please tell me]]

Comment: @TomM How do you define "can be computed easily"? -- $f$ cannot even be continuous by parts

Comment: I don't :)
I'm trying to find the best that I can, so obviously if I can compute it by hand (e.g. summation, multiplication etc...) that's the optimal way, but otherwise even a complicated function that you have to use a computer for would be fine.
However I would say that a function that does exist but without any known way of computing would be defined as "not computed easily".
In other words if you can show me an algorithm that produces the result of the function (in reasonable time) given an input, I would consider it "computed easily". (haven't defined reasonable time though :) )

Comment: So any f that fulfills the requirement is going to be discontinuous everywhere?

Comment: For instance if it's going to not be continuous by parts that means it can't be represented as a combination of simple operations such as addition/subtraction, multiplication/division, exponent/log.
That means we're in another realm. However dirichlet's function for instance should be considered "easily computable" and is discontinuous everywhere.
Therefore if I can find an "easily computable" discontinuous everywhere function I should still be able to compute the dot product easily even though the function itself is not continuous.